# Error while installing angular cli globally

Tags: node.js, angular, intellij-idea, angular-cli

I am new to this platform. I am using IntelliJ Idea Ultimate edition. I installed node js version v10.14.2.

I tried using the command  `npm install -g @angular/cli` I received the following error.

```
npm ERR! path C:\Users\D\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.cmd
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! Refusing to delete C:\Users\D\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.cmd: node_modules\angular-cli\bin\ng symlink target is not controlled by npm C:\Users\D\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\D\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.cmd
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.
```

I am unsure to figure out what is the problem here. Any lead would be really helpful.

After I tried to install , I am getting the below error

```
npm WARN deprecated angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.28.3: angular-cli has been renamed to @angular/cli. Please update your dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated exists-sync@0.0.3: Please replace with usage of fs.existsSync
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated boom@2.10.1: This version is no longer maintained. Please upgrade to the latest version.
npm WARN deprecated cryptiles@2.0.5: This version is no longer maintained. Please upgrade to the latest version.
npm WARN deprecated hoek@2.16.3: This version is no longer maintained. Please upgrade to the latest version.
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.7: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
C:\Users\D\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng -> C:\Users\D\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\bin\ng

> node-sass@4.11.0 install C:\Users\DRAJKUM3\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.11.0/win32-x64-64_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.11.0/win32-x64-64_binding.node":

tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND f.com f.com:8080

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

      export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

      npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

> node-sass@4.11.0 postinstall C:\Users\D\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\D\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\D\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\angular-cli\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@10.14.2 | win32 | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\D\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\D\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\D\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\D\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\D\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\D\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 { Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\DRAJKUM3\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\D\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\D\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\D\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\D\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\D\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:21)
gyp verb `which` failed   stack:
gyp verb `which` failed    'Error: not found: python2\n    at getNotFoundError (C:\\Users\\D\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\angular-cli\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n    at F (C:\\Users\\DRAJKUM3\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\angular-cli\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n    at E (C:\\Users\\DRAJKUM3\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\angular-cli\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n    at C:\\Users\\DRAJKUM3\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\angular-cli\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n    at C:\\Users\\DRAJKUM3\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\angular-cli\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n    at C:\\Users\\DRAJKUM3\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\angular-cli\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Users\D\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.EXE
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Users\D\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                                ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\D\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\angular-cli\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\D\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v10.14.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN @angular/core@2.4.10 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.11.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.11.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I have already installed PYTHON and set it to the env variables. I did the same for GIT as well.

EDIT2 Error with build process

```
The projects in this solution are created one after the other. To enable a parallel creation, you must add the "/ m" switch.
The build process was started on 02.01.2019 14:34:39.
Project "C: \ Users \ D \ IdeaProjects \ AngularHelloWorld \ helloworld \ node_modules \ node-sass \ build \ binding.sln" on node "1" (default destinations).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
The solution configuration "Release | x64" is created.
MSBUILD: error MSB3428: Could not load Visual C ++ component VCBuild.exe. To fix this problem, install either 1) the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK or 2) Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component m Add system path if it is different from the default location. [C: \ Users \ D \ Idea Projects \ AngularHelloWorld \ helloworld \ node_modules \ node-sass \ build \ binding.sln]
Creation of the project "C: \ Users \ D \ IdeaProjects \ AngularHelloWorld \ helloworld \ node_modules \ node-sass \ build \ binding.sln" is complete (default targets) - ERROR.


Error during the build process.

The projects in this solution are created one after the other. To enable a parallel creation, you must add the "/ m" switch.
The build process was started on 02.01.2019 14:34:39.
Project "C: \ Users \ D \ IdeaProjects \ AngularHelloWorld \ helloworld \ node_modules \ node-sass \ build \ binding.sln" on node "1" (default destinations).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
The solution configuration "Release | x64" is created.
MSBUILD: error MSB3428: Could not load Visual C ++ component VCBuild.exe. To fix this problem, install either 1) the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK or 2) Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component
m Add system path if it is different from the default location. [C: \ Users \ D \ Idea Projects \ AngularHelloWorld \ helloworld \ node_modules \ node-sass \ build \ binding.sln]
Creation of the project "C: \ Users \ D \ IdeaProjects \ AngularHelloWorld \ helloworld \ node_modules \ node-sass \ build \ binding.sln" is complete (default targets) - ERROR.

    Error during the build process.

    "C: \ Users \ D \ IdeaProjects \ AngularHelloWorld \ helloworld \ node_modules \ node-sass \ build \ binding.sln" (default destination) (1) ->
    (_src_ \ libsass destination) ->
      MSBUILD: error MSB3428: Could not load Visual C ++ component VCBuild.exe. To fix this problem, install either 1) .NET Framework 2.0 SDK or 2) Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component
    to the system path if it differs from the default location. [C: \ Users \ D \ Idea Projects \ AngularHelloWorld \ helloworld \ node_modules \ node-sass \ build \ binding.sln]
```

Comment: You could try doing what the error message is telling you to do. Have you?

Comment: @JBNizet As far I understood from the error message , I tried to delete the node modules

Comment: That's not what the error message is telling you. It's telling you that the file C:\Users\D\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.cmd exists, and suggests that you move it away, and then try again.

Comment: Are you in windows?

Comment: yes @RafaelLucini

Comment: I think you have to run in as admin. You already have the angular/cli installed so it have to remove it first.

Comment: I am running as an admin @piotrszybicki

Comment: Ok, then maybe just remove the file manually?

Comment: @piotrszybicki Yeah will try that way

Comment: @piotrszybicki I removed it manually and it worked

Comment: @piotrszybicki It throws me a different error now

Comment: Try to set the proxy you must be behind some corporate firewall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are using Python 3.x

```
...
Error: Command failed: C:\Users\D\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
...
```

`node-gyp` documentation says that Python 3.x is *not* supported
https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp

Try uninstalling Python completely and installing v2.7

UPD:

**Why do you even need `node-gyp`?** If you look at the lines

```
Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.11.0/win32-x64-64_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.11.0/win32-x64-64_binding.node":
```

you'll see that your installation tries to download prebuilt version of `node-sass` for your env but fails. After that the program will download `node-sass` sources and build them ad-hoc. This step requires `node-gyp` to be installed and ready for use.

Comment: Yeah I figured this out few min ago and tried doing it. I am getting an error during the build process

Comment: What does your 
`python -V` says?

Comment: Version of Python is 2.7

Comment: Ok, the problem is definitely with `node-gyp`.
Try to follow the steps for windows from https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp
Ensure you have launched your `cmd` with Admin rights.
It's also a good idea to make a system restart

Answer (score 1):

Steps for Windows:

1. First Check Node JS latest version has been installed properly or not by command

   > node --version

Then follow below steps :

```
> npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
> npm cache clean
> npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: when I am trying to use the cache clean , then i am getting the error "  As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify' instead. On the other hand, if you're debugging an issue with the installer, you can use `npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache` to use a temporary cache instead of nuking the actual one"

Comment: you can see my edit. I have posted my error there. It says checking for python executable 2python" in the path

Comment: what is node version?

Comment: it is  V 10.14.2